# What does Vim use for restoring visual selection on 'gv' besides < and > marks?

Tags: vim, selection

`gv` can be used for starting Visual mode using previous selection. The boundaries are stored in `<` and `>` marks. But marks only contain (line, column) for a file, which is not enough for restoring visual selection region.

For example, `<` = (1, 0) and `>` = (2, 2) could mean either a Visual block selection region:

```
XXX foo bar
XXX quux
```

or a Visual character selection region:

```
XXX XXX XXX
XXX quux
```

or a Visual line selection region:

```
XXX XXX XXX
XXX XXXX
```

Moreover, the cursor position has to be restored as well.

Where does Vim store information about the last Visual sub-mode and the cursor position for restoring visual selection?

Comment: Please take a look at `:h visualmode()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The start and end position are stored in the `'<` and `'>` marks.
- The type of visual mode is stored elsewhere; from Vimscript you access this information via `visualmode()`.
- The cursor position is stored internally; I don't think this is accessible from Vimscript (other than doing `gv`).

If this isn't just a theoretical question, please tell us what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Is it true that the cursor position for the stored visual selection is _always_ `'>` mark's line and column?

Comment: No, the cursor can be at the beginning, too (with `o`), or even somewhere in the middle (e.g. in linewise mode).

Comment: Actually my experiments with `o` and with line-wise visual selection have shown, that `'>` still contains the actual cursor position for `gv` to restore.

Answer (score 1):

It stores it only iternally in the source code, it is not publicly available

Comment: It stores... runtime data in the source code? That's confusing

Comment: Well, it always stores the state, exactly for the reason, to use that data again.

Comment: Yeah, I get that @Christian. But that means it stores it somewhere in memory. That's a different place :)

Comment: So, `gv` doesn't really use `<` and `>` marks and stores previous selection data internally, right?

Answer (score 1):

The question that is being begged here is "what are you trying to achieve". What do you want to know this for?

#### Operator pending/visual mode mappings

Then there is the sample in the vimdoc here: [http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:map-operator](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3amap-operator)

```
  if a:0  " Invoked from Visual mode, use '< and '> marks.
    silent exe "normal! `<" . a:type . "`>y"
  elseif a:type == 'line'
    silent exe "normal! '[V']y"
  elseif a:type == 'block'
    silent exe "normal! `[\<C-V>`]y"
  else
    silent exe "normal! `[v`]y"
  endif
```

#### Anything else

You can probably best look at the source

Comment: I'm trying to understand which selection region is used for `:'<,'>` ranges, but since this syntax only specifies lines, not columns, my question could be pointless, right? I mean storing column position in `<` and `>` marks doesn't seem to be useful.

Comment: @AndreyVlasovskikh Why not? I do jump to `\`>` or `\`<` some times. They're just marks, and it's useful to have the column info there